# An answer disappeared. How can I get it back at least for me (private)?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-answers

I've posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70079323/whats-the-difference-between-ldr-pc-boot-and-b-boot) recently and two answers were posted, one of which was long and detailed. Additionally, I extensively wrote comments on it with the author to clarify some things.

Suddenly, from one day to the other, the whole answer and all comments disappeared as if they had never existed.

I read that sometimes a moderator or the author himself deletes the responses, but shouldn't I at least get a notification on it? As far as I know, I cannot even send the author a personal message to ask him/her if he/she knows what happened. And I myself am not a 10k+ user, so I don't have any ability to still be able to read it, if it really got deleted. I don’t know if it matters, but the answer had no downvotes the last time I looked at it.

The thing is that although the lost answer was pretty long and complicated to read, it provided a lot of information and I would regret it if I'd lost it forever.

If this is really a normal thing that can happen, I would be required to store away every answer that I get on any question as it *could* suddenly disappear.

Comment: The answer was deleted by the author. Only they can tell you why they deleted it, but I assume that had good reason to. You'll only likely get an answer from the author if they stumble onto this question which is highly unlikely. Looking at their meta profile, as they have never commented, never answered, asked once (in 2016), never flagged [successfully], never editted, and voted *once* in 13~ years.

Comment: You could ping them as they seem to have commented on [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70079323/whats-the-difference-between-ldr-pc-boot-and-b-boot#comment123890085_70079563). It depends on whether they wish to respond...

Comment: Note that 3 10K reputation users *could* vote to undelete the answer as well, however, considering it doesn't have any upvotes, and the subject matter isn't my expertise, I (personally) would not be and I find it unlikely others will as well without strong reasons to vote to undelete it. (And even if it were, unless it gets upvotes or accepted as the solution, that won't stop the OP just deleting it again.)

Comment: "*shouldn't I at least get a notification on it?*" I think if you have *followed* the answer, you will get notified when it's deleted, though there's still nothing you can do after that. "*If this is really a normal thing that can happen,*" I don't think it's that normal, but it does happen and the OP is free to delete their own posts as long as it's not somehow abused.

Comment: @Andrew T. Ok, by following you mean give it an upvote? Can you still read it as a 10k+ user or just tell that it indeed got deleted?

Comment: No, by "following" they mean the "Follow" button below answers (next to "Edit" and "Flag").

Comment: @Stone posts on here are soft-deleted, never hard-deleted (unless on very rare occasions). 10k+ users can always see deleted posts.

Comment: @JeanneDark Oh right!! I've never even noticed that!! thanks!

Comment: @Andrew T. Ok thanks, could I suggest to you or any other 10k+ user that are reading this post to copy & paste the post in question here? This would resolve the matter for me at least regarding the loss of information.

Comment: We can't really post the answer here. It isn't an answer to **this** question and it's too long for a comment. Fortunately your comment has encouraged the answerer to undelete their answer.

Comment: If an answer was deleted and you need to see it with less than 10,000 reputation, you'll need to find a friendly 10k user to post a screenshot for you, if the author of the answer isn't willing to undelete it/able to be pinged anywhere. You might find a fair amount of sympathy where it's on your own question and the answer's a decent-looking one.

Comment: The matter is basically resolved as the author reposted his response on request. Altough I must admit that I lost a bit of trust in the way SO is managed. The fact that you have so little control on the answeres that you receive and so little information available (e.g. no reasons are provided if you get a downvote), especially if you are a fairly new user, leaves a bad taste. I mean, I didn't know what to think or if I had gone mad as the answer was suddenly gone without a trace. You are basically reminded all the time that you are worth nothing until you gain reputation in the first place.

Comment: Why should you have any kind of "control" over other users' content? You're using a free service run by unpaid volunteers.

Comment: @MikeM. For the same reason why other users can just change my original question and even delete full sentences without my consent or even knowledge, like it happened in this very post, as I just realized. There's just this complete unbalance of rights amongst different users which does not exactly encourage new users to feel appreciated and welcomed in this community, but maybe this is just my opinion.

Comment: @Stone There is a possibility that you are very mistaken. Let me put it differently; it is not set in stone that you are right. If you allow that to be true, I would suggest you take the next step and maybe go try and prove yourself wrong. It's the only way you allow yourself to actually go find out.

Comment: So, effectively, you posted a question, someone answered it, and then you proceeded to ask followup/implementation questions back and forth tying up this expert user with helping you rather than answering more questions and when they grew tired of the exchange decided their effort wasn't good for the network. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @KevinB Well, actually I was genuinly interested to know more, and not trying to challange his point of view at all! I really hope he sees it this way and find it really unfortuante that someone could understand my curiosity wrong.

Comment: Given the exchange, I don't think they thought you were saying they were wrong or anything like that. It's just, this is a Q&A site, and comments are... secondary. The meat and potatoes should be in the form of questions and answers. It's kinda irritating to go through a long drawn out process of explaining everything in comments knowing that all of that information will be hard for future users to find.

Comment: @KevinB - While I agree, and have experienced the Wonderland Rabbit hole of questions within a commentary scenario, what should have happen is simply ignoring commentary and flagging it as unnecessary. Of course the answer would have to address the question as it was proposed, for me as an author, to feel comfortable leaving my answer in that situation. However, I have also been there, where nothing seems to be enough for the wonderland rabbit and I simply delete my answer.

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't disagree, that the author of the answer took the wrong approach to resolving the situation. I'm simply pointing out what likely lead to it.

Comment: Basically, the way you feel about the deleted answer is *exactly* how we feel about that comment thread: it's just wasted information because it will be impossible to use for anyone in the future. Getting dragged into such trail of comments can be very frustrating for an answerer; it gives the impression that one just cannot satisfy the asker and all the effort is wasted.

Comment: @KevinB I see it exactly the same way as you. I am also not a fan of writing in these small comments sections where you can hardly use any formatting and not even newlines. The problem is that sometimes follow-up questions arise after answers and I honestly don't know where to put them. I tried to put them in the original question by editing it but this makes it really more confusing than helpfull. And opening-up a new question is not really an option either, as in the end it is just a "short" follow-up question related to a specific answer.

Comment: You just have to know where to draw the line. It'll come with experience.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah probably... It's just tempting to keep asking once you found somebody who apparently has your answeres :)

Comment: If you found it helpful, you should have accepted it by clicking on the green checkmark. Not only is it a good idea to accept an answer that solves your problem, but it would also have prevented the author from deleting it.

Comment: That is why the 10,000 reputation points privilege is the [second-most](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiYd4-9aNyI&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFUOPyA8aLONTz5jr-IQFu5&index=8&t=0m3s) important privilege (yes, not a perfect match).

Answer (score -9):

Anyway, thanks for your help everybody. I guess I can wrap it up by stating that if an answer suddenly disappeared it's (usually) not you who went crazy but the author who decided to delete it for whatever reason and you have to get in touch with them and try to convince them to post it back or give you access to it in any other way.

Good to know for the future!

Comment: Re _and you have to get in touch with him and try to convince him to post it back_ or you could just respect their decision and leave them alone

Comment: Why didn't you accept the answer that helped you the most then? If you had accepted it, it's as if the answer *also* belongs to you in a sharing sense(not legal) and SO prevents authors from deleting accepted answers.

Comment: @TheMaster I did not know that SO prevents accepted answers from deletion. In fact I did not even know that deliting ones answers was so common amongst SO (I'm pretty new & don't have much experience yet with SO tbh). Moreover unfortunately you cannot accept more answers as solution (as far as I know at least). In this particular case the first answer I received actually solved my confusion - so technically it should be accepted. Though the answer from old_timer provided a lot of background info which was great as well. I don't know how to handle this situation so that everybody is satisfied.

Comment: Deletion is not common. In fact you can't delete more than 5 answers in a time period. I maybe wrong, but It is possible that old_timer deleted his post because you accepted the other one. But if you think the original one is the one that should be accepted, that is fine as well: You can't satisfy them all.(But if you do get enough reps, you may award bounties)

Comment: @TheMaster Ah ok good to know, thanks. I will try to increase my reputation. The few questions I wrote so far got only downvotes and I cannot really imagine how one can ever reach above 10k reps, but I'll try not to lose faith on the way ^^ Edit: No actually I received 1 upvote recently, I'll try keep this trend going :)